# In Python, how to make a regular expression not ignore the next regular expression if the latter is 'optional'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a parser for expressions such as

> "Weekly from 2017-11-03 15:00:00 till 2017-11-03 16:00:00 until 2017-12-03"

which represent a recurring interval of time. Eventually I would like to be able to initialize a [dateutil.rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) object with the parsed fields. Most of the `rrule` parameters are optional, however, which in the string representation corresponds to patterns which may or may not be there.

However, I'm having trouble preventing preceding patterns from being 'too greedy'. Consider the following example with two test cases:

```
import re
import pytest

from dateutil.rrule import FREQNAMES

def match_pattern(string):
    SPACES = r'\s*'

    freq_names = [freq.lower() for freq in FREQNAMES] + [freq.title() for freq in FREQNAMES]
    FREQ_PATTERN = '(?P<freq>{})?'.format("|".join(freq_names))

    START_PATTERN = 'from' + SPACES + r'(?P<start>.+)'
    END_PATTERN = 'till' + SPACES + r'(?P<end>.+)'

    UNTIL_PATTERN = optional('until' + SPACES + r'(?P<until>.+)')
    # UNTIL_PATTERN = 'until' + SPACES + r'(?P<until>.+)'

    PATTERN = SPACES + FREQ_PATTERN \
            + SPACES + START_PATTERN \
            + SPACES + END_PATTERN \
            + SPACES + UNTIL_PATTERN + SPACES

    return re.match(PATTERN, string).groupdict()

def optional(pattern):
    '''Encloses the given regular expression in an optional group (i.e., one that matches 0 or 1 repetitions of the original regular expression).'''
    return '({})?'.format(pattern)

'''Tests'''
def test_match_pattern():
    string = "Weekly from 2017-11-03 15:00:00 till 2017-11-03 16:00:00"

    groups = match_pattern(string)
    assert groups['freq'] == "Weekly"
    assert groups['start'].strip() == "2017-11-03 15:00:00"
    assert groups['end'].strip() == "2017-11-03 16:00:00"

def test_match_pattern_with_until():
    string = "Weekly from 2017-11-03 15:00:00 till 2017-11-03 16:00:00 until 2017-12-03"

    groups = match_pattern(string)
    assert groups['freq'] == "Weekly"
    assert groups['start'].strip() == "2017-11-03 15:00:00"
    assert groups['end'].strip() == "2017-11-03 16:00:00"
    assert groups['until'].strip() == "2017-12-03"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # pytest.main([__file__])
    pytest.main([__file__+"::test_match_pattern", "-s"])
    # pytest.main([__file__+"::test_match_pattern_with_until", "-s"])
```

Here, I would like to make the `UNTIL_PATTERN` optional in the string; therefore I have enclosed it in `()?` using the `optional` function. The problem, however, is that this makes the second test fail:

```
>       assert groups['end'].strip() == "2017-11-03 16:00:00"
E       assert '2017-11-03 1...il 2017-12-03' == '2017-11-03 16:00:00'
E         - 2017-11-03 16:00:00 until 2017-12-03
E         + 2017-11-03 16:00:00

parse_date.py:44: AssertionError
=========================== 1 failed in 0.07 seconds ===========================
```

The problem is that when I make the `UNTIL_PATTERN` optional, the `END_PATTERN` is too greedy and consumes till the end of the string. (If I dispense with making it `optional()`, the second test passes but the first test doesn't yield a match).

How can I make both tests pass?

Comment: Dates, like `2017-11-03 15:00:00`, seem to have a pretty standard format. Try using that information to help with parsing.

Comment: You're actually doing this in the wrong order. The overall pattern must be established / modified / tested, before it is broken up into pieces. This means every contingency must be tested first. This probably means you'd have to lose the dot metachar and replace with a more narrow subexpression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to make two minor changes. First, make the `END_PATTERN` non-greedy:

```
(?P<end>.+?)
```

But now, since it'll match as little as possible, you have to force it to match until the end of the string with an end-of-string anchor `$`:

```
PATTERN = SPACES + FREQ_PATTERN \
        + SPACES + START_PATTERN \
        + SPACES + END_PATTERN \
        + SPACES + UNTIL_PATTERN + SPACES + '$'
```